# Absolutely Continuous Spectrum of an operator $Af(x)=\sin x f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let us consider the following operator 
$$
Af(x)=\sin(x)f(x),
$$
in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

This operator is self-adjoint, so $\sigma(A)\subset \mathbb R.$

Solving equation $(A-\lambda I)f=g,$ we obtain $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}g=\frac{g}{\sin x-\lambda}$, and this formula defines resolvent if $\lambda\in\mathbb R\setminus[-1,1].$

Let $\lambda \in [-1,1].$ From the fact, that $\parallel \frac{1}{\sin x- \lambda}\parallel=\infty$, we get, that $[-1,1]$ is continuous spectrum.

Now I am trying  to check, if this continuous spectrum is (or is not)a absolutely continuous spectrum. I would by very grateful if anyone can give me a hint, how to do that.